# How to add 'awesome' selection in LightDM?

Tags: 13.04, lightdm, session, awesome

I installed `awesome` using `apt-get`, and after installation finished, I logged out to `lightdm`.

But there is no selection for `awesome`, only Unity and `subtle` (since I recently installed `subtle`).

What should I do, in order to make `awesome` selection is available?

There were no errors while installing `awesome`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, it looks like [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1094811), although some of the users found that switching `NoDisplay=true` to `NoDisplay=false` in `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop` was enough (see the comments under the bug description). If this solution works out for you, can you also contribute to the bug report in the link given? :)